# C# PDF render from bytes array sometimes does not load in IE

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, webforms, pdf-generation

I have a c# code which renders PDF in a web form. I get a byte array from "SQL Server reporting service" and write into Response output stream. It works fine in chrome and firefox. In IE however sometimes it renders the PDF file, other times it shows up like below screen shot.

Any idea ?

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", PDFByteArray.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        Response.OutputStream.Write(PDFByteArray, 0, PDFByteArray.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding this solved my issue

```
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", PDFByteArray.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
            Response.OutputStream.Write(PDFByteArray, 0, PDFByteArray.Length);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```